# Insert data from datepicker in database using php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli, php-5.3

I have a problem and I can't resolve it, So my script:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#datepicker").datepicker({
         format: 'dd-mm-yy'
     });
 })
```

My html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <label>Date:</label>
     <input class="form-control marg-left-10" name="date"  type="text" id="datepicker">
 </div>
```

My php:

```
$date = date('dd-mm-yy', strtotime($this->input->post['date']));
```

But the date doesn't insert, in my database the date look like this : 0000-00-00

Help me please

Comment: Please see the solution of this question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20809679/jquery-date-picker-cant-saving-in-database-by-php

Answer (score 4):

Use the appropriate format

```
//converting one date format into another
    $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post['date']));
```

Comment: If I wrote : $date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post['date']));
In my database date is saved:1969-12-31

Comment: It may be the default date. Above posted is a syntax. You want to change `strtotime($this->input->post['date'])` as this `strtotime(//your input date)`

Answer (score 2):

MySQL database supports YYYY-mm-dd date format

So you should change your script...

```
<script>
$(function(){
    var pickerOpts = {
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    };  
    $("#datepicker").datepicker(pickerOpts);
});

</script>
```

Comment: This works for me. It is a strange issue though because my local DB works with dd-mm-yy whereas my remote db only works with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

As You Stated

```
    My php:

$date = date('dd-mm-yy', strtotime($this->input->post['date']));
But the date doesn't insert, in my database the date look like this : 0000-00-00
```

Thing is that you are taking the date in dd-mm-YYYY format while on myswl it is saved as YYYY-mm-dd format

SO its better either you take a colum as varchar and save the date as 'dd-mm-YYYY' as string

or if you want to use mysql date format then covert your date into YYYY-mm-dd format

which can be done like this

```
$old_date = $this->input->post['date'];
$o_date_time = strtotime($o_date);
$date = date('Y-m-d', $o_date_time);
```

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL Support Date Format to save  'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD'

As a string in either 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YY-MM-DD' format. A “relaxed” syntax is permitted: Any punctuation

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html

Change to your code like this

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this->input->post['date']));
```

OR

```
  $date = new DateTime($this->input->post['date']);
  echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Answer (score 0):

First change your formate to this:

```
 $date1=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($fromd));
```

And if you want to change the format then do something like this on the page where you want to show the date..

```
<?php
                                $dte=date_create($rows->database row);
                                echo date_format($dte,'d/m/y');
                                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mysql uses yyyy-mm-dd format so firs tyou have to change your date format and then change the datatype of your date column to text